# Multiple monitors, multiple workspaces?

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

I connected my laptop to my LCD. Using the laptop display hotkey I can switch between different modes - only laptop monitor on, only LCD monitor on, both on and display the same view, both on and the desktop is stretched (divided).

But, I'm looking for something else - I would like to have two workspaces, one visible on the laptop monitor and the other on the LCD.

Is that possible?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/q/5082/275

Comment: It is possible with compiz, but a bit tricky to set up. What graphics card do you have? That could be useful. Are you using metacity?

Comment: I use Asus eee PC 1015PEM. Don't know what metacity is...

Comment: @Marcel Stimberg: the question you referred to was not actually answered IMHO. I don't want "one big screen" where I can drag windows and maximize them so it's "like two separate displays". I want a screen per workspace. No windows dragging and other tricks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacity and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz

Comment: What graphics card/chip is it?

    lspci | grep VGA

Comment: It is a duplicate...but idk what bonus you plan to achieve by having more than one instance of X running...I would think connecting one to 0:0 and one to 0:1 would do it, but why the complication?

Comment: The only possible advantage I can think of is trying to ask this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21198/tutorial-or-livedisk-for-multiseat-setup-with-dual-head-display-supporting-open a different way...

Comment: @David: I agree that the question I linked to has not been answered sufficiently -- still, the question is the same...

Comment: Two different screen can be displayed on LCD and laptop/PC screen by disabling "Mirror displays" in display setting. No need install any additional application.

Answer (score 37):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to be able to switch workspaces independently for each screen, so that for example the left screen could be on workspace 1 and the right screen on workspace 3. This is supported by some window managers, most notably [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/tour.html), and I personally find it extremely convenient in a dual-head setup. Moreover, it's perfectly possible to [integrate XMonad with GNOME](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome) without sacrificing usability.

On my home machine I currently have a much simpler setup, with the default window manager. I like to have a music player visible on one of the screens at all times, so I just pinned the player to the visible workplace in order to emulate a “separate workspace”. This doesn't really solve a problem, but might be helpful anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original question asked this exactly, but another question that exactly matches your answer is http://askubuntu.com/q/126100/7808 - the answer is the same as yours, though.

Comment: I can testify that [i3](http://i3wm.org/) supports it, and I believe [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) does as well.

Comment: +1 because this contains the most relevant answer of today. But it is still really frustrating that none of the standard desktops (KDE, Gnome, etc) supports this really simple feature.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to archive something similar using **nVidia** (prop) driver (*Ge-Force graphics cards*). It is called "**TwinView**". I only tried it once. You may want to read more here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=221174

*I was not able to achieve the same result using an ATI graphics card.*

Comment: When I use twin view on my Asus eee pc 1201n I get one screen with the desktop and another with the desktop background ONLY. and if you look at the workspaces so are they only stretched out! They have put together the resolutions for both screens. 
I have a similar question. NOT a duplicate.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/27527/why-doesnt-my-graphic-card-software-support-12801024

Answer (score 4):

In Gnome

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo gnome-tweaks
```

in the workspaces tab under "display handling" select "workspaces span displays" which means all the screens to act together. (when you switch on one, others will switch to that workspace as well)

you can select whether all the screens act together or individually 
to switch between workspaces press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>UP_ARROW/DOWN_ARROW</kbd>.

Comment: Incorrect, the user requested separate workspace for each screen

Comment: It may be "Incorrect", but that is what I was looking for: Ubuntu workspace switching for all screens.

Comment: Looks like this package has been replaced by [gnome-tweaks](https://packages.debian.org/stable/gnome/gnome-tweaks).

Answer (score 2):

I guess what we (or at least I) really want is to get the top & bottom panels on both monitors and have the bottom panel's application tabs only on the corresponding monitor.

Looks like it's not there yet but we can vote for it [on ubuntu brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ideatorrent/idea/19336).

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a working xorg.conf for multiple cards multiple desktops using a displaylink usb adapter: http://mulchman.org/blog/?tag=displaylink