# Switch workspaces individually on each monitor on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

Since it has been so many years since this was asked - [Switch workspaces individually on each monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126100/switch-workspaces-individually-on-each-monitor), I wanted to revive it.

In Ubuntu 20.04, is there finally a way that one could switch workspaces individually on multiple monitors (I would be happy if there was a way to make it work for 2 monitors)?

With the GNOME that comes with Ubuntu 20.04, the default behaviour is that I can change workspaces on my primary display while the secondary display remains fixed on one workspace.

I can install GNOME tweaks and then have a single workspace span across both monitors, implying that when I change workspace on one monitor, the workspace on the other monitor would also change.

What I want is to be able to change workspaces individually on both my monitors. This is allowed by some window managers like awesome, xmonad and i3. I am looking for a DE for Ubuntu that would provide this functionality.