# allocate each workspace to each monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have 2 monitors - 1 is my laptop's and 1 that I use as second (but if this works, I would like to extend that to 4 monitors) and I would like to have each workspace in each monitor.

The idea is to have in my laptop the working workspace and in the rest the others, then I can switch using the 'workspace switcher' easily to have in my laptop's screen the workspace I wish. Also, I need to easily drop apps to each workspace using the Crtl+Alt- keys. I have the second monitor working but it's just a stretched extension of my current workspace.

Any suggestions with step-by-step solution? I know this has been answered before, but all posts are more than 3 years old and the solutions are not perfectly working in current version. Note: I have Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces

Comment: So I suppose the answer is by using xmonad? I was looking for some step-by-step guides, especially if there is another way to do it.