# Limit <ALT> + <TAB> to one screen

Tags: 14.04

I'm using two screens - one is the laptop itself, and one is external.

Is there a way to limit the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to only one screen?

For example, if I have the following apps opened in the first screen:

> Google Chrome, Eclipse, PyCharm

and these on the laptop's screen:

> Terminator, VisualVM

If I'm working on the first screen, I want <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to view only apps that are opened in that screen.

Is this possible to distinguish between apps opened in different screens? Is Linux aware of this at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since what you describe can be done by having the different sets of applications in different Workspaces, the problem is now reduced to having 2 different workspaces on 2 different screens.

That is, have

> Google Chrome, Eclipse, PyCharm

in one workspace and,

> Terminator, VisualVM

in another workspace.

Now, have the workspaces in different screens.

This seems to have been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Quoting the answer from the above link,

> If I understand the question correctly, you would like to be able to switch workspaces independently for each screen, so that for example the left screen could be on workspace 1 and the right screen on workspace 3. This is supported by some window managers, most notably [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/tour.html), and I personally find it extremely convenient in a dual-head setup. Moreover, it's perfectly possible to [integrate XMonad with GNOME](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome) without sacrificing usability.

Another useful comment from the above link,

> I can testify that [i3](http://i3wm.org/) supports it, and I believe [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) does as well.

Credits :
This is taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces?answertab=votes#tab-top) link.
The quoted answer is by [Adam Byrtek](https://askubuntu.com/users/11976/adam-byrtek)
The quoted comment is by [Gordon Gustafson](https://askubuntu.com/users/2671/gordon-gustafson)