# How can I have 2 applications on 2 different displays in Ubuntu?

Tags: display, application-switcher, multiple-desktops

I have an external display connected to my laptop. How can I have the external display show a different application than the one shown on the builtin display?

I have disabled mirror display but there doesn't seem to be any documentation about opening or keeping an application on the external display.

Edit: This is not about workspaces, so is not a duplicate of the workspaces related question as flagged by some users.

I have two applications running side-by-side **in the same workspace**. I just want to move one of them to an external display, so that both applications can each have more screen space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple monitors, multiple workspaces?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces)

Comment: Why not add the answer to the other question? If it is correct it will rise to the top regardless if the other answer was accepted.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of an older question. Asking the same question so you can answer it yourself, to gain reputation, is inappropriate. You should participate in existing questions by suggesting an alternate answer there, instead.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, because I am not really concerned with workspaces, but to have different applications on different screens. I am modifying the question accordingly.

Comment: Have modified the question and added images to the answer. Hope this clarifies why this is a different question and answered appropriately with the intention to share knowledge, not for reputation.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer The OP of the question being linked here as a duplicate, very specifically mentions that he wants different "workspaces" on different screens, not different applications on different screens. I am just concerned with different applications on different screens, for example, I want a stock market screener on external display while I blog on the main display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version is 14.04, and I use the standard desktop given by Canonical - Unity.

Using the workspace switcher, we can shift application(s) display to the 2nd monitor, by just dragging it.

Here's how to do it after connecting external display to laptop:

- Enable workspaces 
  [image]
- Disable mirror display 
  [image]
- Open/Highlight (bring to front) the application window that needs to be shifted to external display
  [image]
- Press Super + S 
  [image]
- Both screens are displayed in default workspace
- Drag the application window to 2nd (right-side) screen - leave the remaining 3 workspaces untouched 
  [image]
- Click anywhere on builtin screen. Now the shifted application is seen in external display
  [image]
- To switch mouse activity/focus to external screen, move the pointer beyond the right edge of screen, to bring it back to builtin screen move the pointer beyond the left edge.

PS: both screen and display to refer to the same thing.

Comment: This should be an edit - not an answer. P.S. the "standard desktop given by Canonical" is known as Unity.

Comment: How is it not an answer? The question is "can I shift application to external monitor" and that question is answered!

Comment: Oh, really sorry - glancing at it, it looked like an edit to a question. Unfortunately, StackExchange has no way to undo flags. Sorry.