# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop multihead and per monitor workspaces support

Tags: workspaces

Hello Ubuntu Community =)!

I am a very big fan of separate desktops per monitor or multihead feature. And, I would like to ask for your help.
I would like to ask if there is such a feature where we can set a multihead or a per monitor workspaces in Ubuntu 16.04?
Or if not are there any window manager we can use that supports Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop? I have heard of i3, awesome or xmonad. But I am not sure if these are directly supported by Ubuntu.

Your ideas will be much appreciated =)!

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this has been answered in https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces