# How to make every screen has his own desktop

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

Currently i have 2 screens and i've activated the workspaces feature. When I switch to another workspace, the 2 screens switch the workspace and this isn't the behavior I want.

I want a Mac like workspace support where only the screen I focus switch the workspace.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces

Comment: No i didn't found this thread, i'm going to read it. I only found on the web solutions to use the trackpad like mac to change workspace

Answer (score 1):

In Unity you can right click in the window you want to "pin" and select "Always on visible workspace".

In Gnome, using gnome-tweak-tool, in the Workspaces tab you can choose to activate "Workspaces on primary display only".

Comment: In KDE: Kmenu, System settings, Keyboard and Mouse, Global Keyboard Shortcuts, for KDE component select Kwin Scroll down click on Switch to Desktop 1 select Custom and click in the box right next to Custom. You can enter just about any key combo there.

Comment: In my opinion the question Multiple monitors, multiple workspaces? is slightly different and is not exactly what @kpone is asking.